# Writing python logs to Google Cloud Logging

Tags: python, logging, python-3.4, google-cloud-platform

I have an application running on Google Cloud Compute.

My python logging is currently configured to write to syslog as:

```
import logging
import logging.handlers

logger = logging.getLogger('pyAdminLogger')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(address = '/dev/log')
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

I've been hunting around for a way to get my logs into the Google Cloud Logging API, but I keep coming up empty handed.

As far as I can see I have two options:

1. Use the Google SDK to write logs (I really don't want to add this as a dependency on my code)
2. Install google-fluentd on all my instances so that it can steam the syslog.

What I really want is some sort of third option where I can configure the standard python logging to write into the Google Cloud Logging API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those two options are really good. Personally I like installing `google-fluentd` which one can install on an instance and create a template using that instance. Rest is just using that template to launch any new instances.

This frees up codebase responsibility to include and maintain any external libraries. Moreover if you were to ever switch to another cloud provider you can easily keep writing logs to syslog and stream them out of instance using some other provider.

Other than these options there is also [gcloud-python](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-python/) which is provided by cloud team. Though seems like its not up-to-date with beta apis, logging being one of them.